Monthly Active Users on Purview Catalog Adoption
I am exploring the adoption metrics of Microsoft Purview Data Catalog, particularly focusing on the “Catalog Adoption” section where we can see the count of monthly active users. I am looking for an API or method that can provide detailed information about these users, such as usernames and their activities.
Specifically, I want to understand how the API that fetches the user count works and where it retrieves this data from internally. I have already tried using Graph API and Management API to access activity logs for Purview, but these did not provide the required details. My primary goal is to obtain data about the users who are active on Purview and the resources they have accessed.

Can you provide your configurations and error for better understanding of the issue?
